# Weka Create and Export Classification on unseen data

Tags: export, classification

i trained a classification model to classify some data. Now I´m at the point to use that model to classify unknown data und categorize instances from my unseen data set into two different classes. Can you explain what I need to do to run that model on that unseen data set? I also want to export those results. How can you do that?

Comment: Do  want to do that in the user interface, command-line or from code?

Comment: In the user interface

Answer (score 0):

Check out the *Explorer* sections in the [Saving and loading models](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/saving_and_loading_models/) or [Making predictions](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/making_predictions/) articles in the [Weka wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/).